# error trying to connect EC2 server to RDS mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

when i call a PHP file (it just echos some text) in my `/var/www/html` directory in my **Ubuntu** server it works. When i try to run this PHP script in my browser (try to connect to my EC2 database):

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("phpmyadmin.cvw71h2krjrb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",root,"phpmyadmin") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Database connected.";

?>
```

i get this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'172.31.56.54' (using password: YES)

My security group is wide open and i know everything works because i can sign into phpMyAdmin and see my databases and i can echo PHP files.

how do i properly connect to a RDS database from a EC2 Ubuntu server via PHP? or is there something wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: put your user name inside  double quotations as "root" and make sure your password is correct

Comment: then i get this error code: Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'172.31.56.54' (using password: YES)?

Comment: @Lazar try my answer and then tell what happnes

Comment: @Lazar Make sure that Server name , User name and Password are correct. if you get this error that is the cause

Comment: server name to the RDS? and do i use the same username and password for phpMyAdmin too?

Comment: never mind i got it! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this, remove `:3306` from `phpmyadmin.cvw71h2krjrb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306` and `username` should be surronded by double quotation(`"root"`):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("phpmyadmin.cvw71h2krjrb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com","root","phpmyadmin") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Database connected.";
?>
```